# Match certain instances by sed in Linux

Tags: linux, sed

Experts,
  I have a very basic requirement here to process a string, i.e., I want to replace all but the first of `,` in the string with a space character:

I know to replace all of them, I can do:

```
$ echo "abc,def,ghi,jkl" | sed 's/,/ /g'
abc def ghi jkl
```

To replace only the first 1 of them, I can do:

```
$ echo "abc,def,ghi,jkl" | sed 's/,/ /1'
abc def,ghi,jkl
```

But how do I replace all but the first one of ","? That is, the desired output would be:

```
abc,def ghi jkl
```

Answer (score 2):

quick and dirty:

```
sed 's/,/\x99/;s/,/ /g;s/\x99/,/'
```

or

```
sed 's/,/\x99 /g;s/\x99 /,/;s/\x99//g'
```

same idea

Comment: Hi, Kent, Thanks, it works. But this is just an example, in real situation, we do not know how many the match pattern of "," will be there. So it would be better to have a more generalized solution of it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, just checked that it works for any number of matched patterns. So this looks like a general solution. Thanks!

Comment: @user1460691: There is no hard-coded limit in Kent's answer. He's chosen `0x99` as a dummy character assumed not to be in the original input, so he can temporarily replace the 1st `,` instance and later restore it.

Comment: i used `\x99` because it is an invisible char, you can choose another char, like `#`, but the transformation will fail if your text contains `#` too. it doesn't mean 99 times.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/(,.*),/\1 /;ta' file
```

This use greed to work backwards through the sting replacing all but the first `,` with spaces.

Alternatively, working forwards use:

```
sed -r ':a;s/(,[^,]*),/\1 /;ta' file
```

Or use this, peculiar to GNU:

```
sed 's/,/ /2g' file
```